# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$, then the sequence $a_n = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n f\!\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right) - \ln n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $f: (-c, c) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $c$ is some possitive real number, and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$. I need to prove that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\ a_n = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n f\!\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right) - \ln n$ converges.

Now, this exercise is in a highschool level textbook and we don't do asymptotic analysis in highschool where I live, but I feel that it might be really easy using little-o notation. The problem is that I know very little asymptotic analysis (I know what each Landau notation means and basic properties of them) and I tried to prove it but I don't know how to continue and your help would be appreciated.

Firstly, I note that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 \iff f(x) = x + o(x),\ x\to 0$$
And then I reverse the order of summation so that I can see that:
$$\begin{align*}&\sum_{k=1}^n f\!\left(\frac{1}{k}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n f\!\left(\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right) \\
&\frac{1}{n-k+1} \to 0,\ n \to \infty \\ &f\!\left(\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right) = \frac{1}{n-k+1} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right),\ n\to\infty \end{align*}$$
So the sequence $a_n$ is
$$\begin{align*} a_n &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} f\!\left(\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right)\right) - \ln n \\
&= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n-k+1} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right)\right)-\ln n \\ &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n-k+1}\right) + o\!\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n-k+1}\right) - \ln n \\ &= H_n - \ln n + o(H_n) \end{align*} $$

And now I don't know how to continue. I know that $H_n - \ln n$ is convergent and its limit is $\gamma$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant, and also I know that $o(H_n) \subseteq o(n)$ (I think)

Answer (score 2):

That is actually not true due to a lack of uniformity. For instance, by considering
$$ f(x) = x+\frac{x}{\log\left(10+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}$$
over $(-1,1)$ (with $f(0)$ being defined as zero) we have 
$$ f\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n\log(10+n^2)}$$
$$ a_n = (H_n-\log n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k\log(10+k^2)} $$
where $H_n-\log n$ does converge to $\gamma$ but $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k\log(10+k^2)}$ is divergent.
Probably some hypothesis on $f$ is missing, like its differentiability or Holder-continuity at the origin.

Comment: Probably the textbook authors found this exercise somewhere and there was another condition on f, but they missed it or thought it wasn't important or not appropriate for the level the students should be at when solving those problems, as we haven't studied differentiability, nor continuity yet (I have studied them alone however). I wish I knew the textbook, cause the problems were sent by my teacher as a pdf which starts with page 104, so it's clearly taken from some textbook

Comment: Wait, how do you claim that you can _define_ f(0) = 0, when there is a point of discontinuity there? Since f has to be defined on the entire (-c, c), this seems like it invalidates your answer

Comment: @StefanOctavian: being defined and being continuous are two different things.

Comment: Yes, I know, the function is continuous at x=0, but 0 is not in its domain. I didn't mean point of discontinuity, I meant that the function should not be defined at x=0 unless explicitly defined as f(0) = 0 using branch notation. At first it seemed to me like there was a discontinuity there, sorry